# Passing a class to two navbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using two navbars. Both of them share a single class ('navbar-item'). Basically both navbars do the same things.

E.g.

navbar-1

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="#Services">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i></span>
  <span>Services</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-item" href="#Delivery">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span>
  <span>Delivery</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-item" href="#Contact">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span>
  <span>Contact</span>
</a>
```

navbar-2

```
<li class="navbar-item"><a href="#Services"></a></li>
<li class="navbar-item"><a href="#Delivery"></a></li>
<li class="navbar-item"><a href="#Contact"></a></li>
```

I am looking to add/remove another class name ('current') when clicked. I want to add this new class name ('current') to both navbars. So when "Services" is clicked, in both navbrs only the "Services" should have the class `current`. When "Delivery" is clicked, in both navbrs only the "Delivery" should have the class `current`.

I am looking for a pure js solution (no jQuery). This is what I have so far.
This passes the new class name (`current`) only to the first navbar.

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-item");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("current");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" current", "");
    this.className += " current";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
>   NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
>   specified group of selectors.

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav.navbar-item')
                .forEach((node) => node.className += ' current')
```

Here, `nav.navbar-item` is the selection required, and `current` is the new class to be appended to the nodes selected by querySelector.

Adding verbose solution:

```
let classToBeAdded = 'current';//new class to be added
let myNavs = document.querySelectorAll('nav.navbar-item');//Selects all navs with the given class
for(let element of myNavs) {//looping through the elements captured by the above query
    element.classList.add(classToBeAdded);//Appending new class to the element
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if this is the solution. Let me give it a try.

Comment: This is the simplest/cleanest solution I could think of. I can update with a verbose solution if you need help.

Comment: Thanks Aditya... but this doesn't seem to pass the class to both navbars at the same time? E.g. When an item is clicked in navbar-1, the class ('active') should be passed on to the same relevant item in navbar-2 too.

Comment: I did not understand the question. This code just updates the new class. You will have to write the logic for event listener, etc.

Comment: Also, if you check the 2 navs in chrome dev tools, it does update both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Note:- this is the way you can detect selected div using that you can toggle(add/remove) class based on the selected element.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("First");
div1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (event.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove('active');
      var element = document.getElementById("Second");
      element.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
      var element = document.getElementById("Second");
      element.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
var div2 = document.getElementById("Second");
div2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (event.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove('active');
    var element = document.getElementById("First");
      element.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    var element = document.getElementById("First");
      element.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id"newNav">
  <a class="navbar-item te" id="First" href="#Delivery">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span>
  <span>Delivery</span>
  </a>
  <li class="navbar-item" id="Second"><a href="#Delivery"></a>
    <span>Delivery2</span>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to pass the class to both navbars at the same time? E.g. When an item is clicked in `navbar-1`, the class ('active') should be passed on to the same relevant  item in `navbar-2` too.